# Authorize and GetRoles doesn't work in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.1.0 using Entity Framework implementation. 
Authentication works fine but role based security has problem.
Although I've added role to the user but this code returns empty :

```
  var roles= UserManager.GetRoles(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Also Authorization based on roles of logged in user fails. when user redirects to a controller like below application redirects him to the login page.

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public abstract partial class AdminAreaController : Controller
    {
```

In order to add ASP.NET Identity, first, I have created custom user class to add profile data :

```
    public class BasemapUser : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<BasemapUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity =
            await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

This is DbContext class :

```
    public class WebCoreMapDbContext : IdentityDbContext<BasemapUser>
{
    public WebDbContext()
        : base("WebDbContext")
    {
    }

    public static WebCoreMapDbContext Create()
    {
        return new WebCoreMapDbContext();
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new {r.RoleId, r.UserId});
    }
}
```

I created database using EF Migration commands in power shell. I see two extra columns in IdentityUserRoles table which I haven't seen in other samples of ASP.NET identity

[image: Extra columns in IdentityUserRoles]

I used this code to add default admin user and role:

```
        public static void Start()
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<BasemapUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        const string name = "someEmail@gmail.com";
        const string password = "somePassword";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        IdentityRole role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null)
        {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            IdentityResult roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        BasemapUser user = userManager.FindByName(name);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new BasemapUser {UserName = name, Email = name};
            IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        IList<string> rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name))
        {
            IdentityResult result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);

        }
    }
```

Admin user and role have been stored in database successfully but stored record in IdentityUserRoles table contains null value :

[image: Null value]

Why GetRoles returns nothing for the user who has that role in database? also other APIs like IsInRole doesn't work as expected. Is it because foreign keys which added to IdentityUserRoles table?

Comment: What does `BasemapUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync` returns? What does returned `ClaimsIdentity` object has in `.Claims` property?

Comment: @trailmax I have not use that at all. It's just taken from samples of ASP.NET Identity in Nuget.

Comment: Not sure what the sample does - have not looked on it for a while. But it looks like the `ClaimsPrincipal` you get from the framework does not have roles as claims attached (it should). In your Login controller try adding this code and see if generated list of `Claims` has the required role on it or not.

Comment: @trailmaxt I'm afraid I don't understand.
I used the exact code of Nuget sample here => http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1
The sample works fine but my application doesn't. The only difference with the sample and my application is generated FKs which has null value (last image)

Comment: Sorry, did not notice these. I think `IdentityRole_id` and `BasemapUser_id` should not exist and do cause trouble you experience. You'll have to tweak your `WebCoreMapDbContext` to get rid of these key strings by adjusting `IdentityUserRoles` properties.

Comment: @trailmax Thank you. Actually I tried but wasn't successful. Do you have any idea how to get rid of those key strings?

Comment: As far as I remember this `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });` fixed it for me, but you already have it. Need to go into your DB models and EF configuration to figure out. Do you have properties called `IdentityRole_Id` and `BasemapUser_Id` somewhere? these are not coming from Identity framework, these are from your code.

Comment: Good! glad it sorted out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was unnecessary columns which have added to Identity tables.

Since DbContext extends from IdentityDbContext, I have to call base.OnModelCreating since the IdentityDbContext defines it for mapping Identity classes. I haven't called that in the my code which caused the issues

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new {r.RoleId, r.UserId});
    }
```

Has to change to

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      // modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);                // do not add this
      // modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new {r.RoleId, r.UserId});         // do not add this
      // other mapping codes
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot shaahin, its solved my problem after a long struggle. and  Am sharing my comments here because if anyone faced this same problem , this solution will surely work .all the best