# UserRole table has duplicate but differently named columns, causes role checking issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

My project makes use of Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Framework and until recently was using version 2.0 and working properly. I noticed back then that the UserRole table  had 4 columns holding essentially the same data:

[image]

Ever since upgrading to 2.1, it seems to leave the second set [Null] - which is a good thing as far as I am concerned (I cannot find where those extra columns have been defined.)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new
        {
            r.RoleId, 
            r.UserId
        }).ToTable("UserRole");;
```

The issue arises when I go to use it:

```
await _manager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser.Id, "Admin");
```

calling this populates the first two columns, whereas:

```
var userRoles = await _manager.GetRolesAsync(applicationUser.Id);
```

seems to query the second set of columns. I know this because they return [Null] unless I copy and paste the values across from the first two columns.

I have been looking all over my code for anything that may shed some light on this but I will admit to being at a complete loss at this point.

Comment: could it be that your Entity Model or table needs to be refreshed have you gone back into the project and manually executed the UPDATE ...this is the only thing that I can think of off the bat..

Comment: do you mean the 'update-database' command in powershell? if so, yes, i've done a few migrations since...

Comment: Columns `ApplicationUser_Id` and `IdentityRole_Id` should not be in that table. You need to adjust your models/dbContext to take these columns out.

Comment: The only table being extended is the User table. From what I gather, it looks like it is not picking up on the key colunns, and has created the additional columns based on the original names of referenced db's. As I mentioned, creating a role does so in the correct columns, getting roles seems to get from the additional columns. There is a disconnect somewhere between the INSERT and the SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some judicious searching, I found this [Authorize and GetRoles doesn't work in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461703/authorize-and-getroles-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-identity?rq=1) post. This combined with some editing of the migration solved the problem.

To Summarize:

I added

```
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

to my context file
and edited the model generation portion

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");

        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<IdentityUserRole>(u => u.Roles);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new
        //{
        //    r.RoleId, 
        //    r.UserId
        //});
```

Your migration code tries to delete some columns and rename others, so instead of delete and rename, I had it delete the columns it was going to rename and kept the pre-existing columns. To drop the pre-existing columns, you will have to remove the Foreign keys as well. I also had to prevent it from re-creating primary keys.

```
        DropIndex("dbo.UserClaim", new[] { "ApplicationUser_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.UserLogin", new[] { "ApplicationUser_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.UserRole", new[] { "ApplicationUser_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.UserRole", new[] { "IdentityRole_Id" });
        DropForeignKey("FK_dbo_UserClaim_ApplicationUser_Id", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        DropForeignKey("FK_dbo_UserLogin_ApplicationUser_Id", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        DropForeignKey("FK_dbo_UserRole_ApplicationUser_Id", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        DropForeignKey("FK_dbo_UserRole_IdentityRole_Id", "Identity_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.UserClaim", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.UserLogin", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.UserRole", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.UserRole", "IdentityRole_Id");
        //DropPrimaryKey("dbo.UserLogin");
        //DropPrimaryKey("dbo.UserRole");
        AlterColumn("dbo.User", "Email", c => c.String(maxLength: 256));
        AlterColumn("dbo.User", "UserName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256));
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserClaim", "UserId", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserClaim", "UserId", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserLogin", "LoginProvider", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserLogin", "ProviderKey", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserLogin", "UserId", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserRole", "UserId", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserRole", "RoleId", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Role", "Name", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256));
        //AddPrimaryKey("dbo.UserLogin", new[] { "LoginProvider", "ProviderKey", "UserId" });
        //AddPrimaryKey("dbo.UserRole", new[] { "UserId", "RoleId" });
        CreateIndex("dbo.User", "UserName", unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
        CreateIndex("dbo.UserClaim", "UserId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.UserLogin", "UserId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.UserRole", "UserId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.UserRole", "RoleId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Role", "Name", unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");
```

This was a frustrating experience with Microsoft ASP.NEt Identity and I hope the above helps someone keep a few more strands of hair.